# Connect to Spatial SQL Tables from RStudio Connect Server

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, rgdal

I have a shiny app which includes the following connection to a spatial table (containing data uploaded from an ESRI shapefile) in a SQL Server:

```
dsn <- paste0("MSSQL:server=host\\instance;",
              "database=database;",
              "UID=my_username;",
              "PWD=my_password;",
              "trusted_connection=no")

spdf <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = dsn, layer = "my_spatial_table")
```

It works fine from my local Windows machine and retrieves the spatial data as expected.

When I publish this to RSConnect, the connection fails. I can however access the table itself and read it into an R session as tabular data (using the `RODBC` package, and much the same DSN, but without `MSSQL` at the front).

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to read spatial data from tables in SQL Server from an RSConnect Server R session?
2. If not, is there a way to turn the encoded spatial data from tabular form to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` within R?

**Versions**

I'm using rgdal v1.2-15, R version 3.4.2, SQL Server 2016, RSConnect v1.5.8-12

Many thanks for any advice - let me know if more technical detail is needed.

**Edit**:  To access the data in tabular form I use the 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' driver. I'm not sure if there's a different driver I should be using for spatial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the devil is in the detail - although the two machines are running the same versions of R and all R packages, they had different versions of the underlying GDAL and PROJ4 system components, which `rgdal` uses.

**Lesson:** Be extra careful when using packages that rely on system components!

It seems that GDAL v1.11.4 and PROJ4 v4.8.0 is insufficient for `readOGR()` to read spatial tables correctly off MS SQL Server.

GDAL v2.2.0 and PROJ4 v4.9.3 is sufficient (but not perhaps necessary - haven't tested versions in between).